# Batch Script to shutdown Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need the following. A batch script that asks me if I want to shutdown windows 7 (Y/N).. If I click "Y", then Windows 7 shuts down right away.

Please help anyone.

Comment: You will get much more help if you attempt something and show people what you tried

Comment: Here is my original try:

@echo off
SET /P ANSWER="Would you like to shut down Windows (Y/N)?"
shutdown /s /t 00
)

Comment: To ask the user such a question, `choice` is much better than `set /p`. See `choice /?` for usage info.

Answer (score 0):

You will be using SET to read an answer and set to a variable. if/goto statements carry it from there.

The shutdown command changed a bit since XP, but this is what I use for 7.

```
@echo off   
SET /P ANSWER=Did you even try Google (Y/N)?
echo You chose: %ANSWER%
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :yes)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes)
goto :no
:yes
echo You pressed yes!
shutdown /f /s /t 01 
:no
echo You pressed no!
shutdown
exit /b 1
```

First link on Google for your search:
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081005123533AALLIPA

Comment: Hi Chris - thank you so much.. I have been looking on Google for about two days.

When I click "y" nothing happens. Any help?

Comment: You can't use a mouse in a batch script without using another helper scripting language or utility.

Comment: I edited the code just a little:

@echo off 

SET /P ANSWER="Do you want to shut down Windows (Y/N)?" 
echo You chose: %ANSWER% 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={y} (goto :yes) 
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={yes} (goto :yes) 
goto :no 
:yes 
echo You pressed yes!
shutdown /f /s /t 01 
:no
echo You pressed no!
shutdown
exit /b 1

Answer (score 0):

The most common ways to use the [`shutdown`][1] command are:

- `shutdown -s` — Shuts down.
- `shutdown -r` — Restarts.
- `shutdown -l` — Logs off.
- `shutdown -h` — Hibernates.

  **Note:** There is a common pitfall wherein users think `-h` means "help" (which it does for every other command-line program... except `shutdown.exe`, where it means "hibernate"). They then run `shutdown -h` and accidentally turn off their computers. Watch out for that.
- `shutdown -i` — "Interactive mode". Instead of performing an action, it displays a GUI dialog.
- `shutdown -a` — Aborts a previous shutdown command.

The commands above can be combined with these additional options:

- `-f` — Forces programs to exit. Prevents the shutdown process from getting stuck.
- `-t <seconds>` — Sets the time until shutdown. Use `-t 0` to shutdown immediately.
- `-c <message>` — Adds a shutdown message. The message will end up in the Event Log.
- `-y` — Forces a "yes" answer to all shutdown queries.